# How can I connect to NFS Client V4 using .net7 and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nfs, nfsclient

I am looking for a NuGet package or library that can help me connect with a v4 NFS client for my dotnet7 web application using C#.

So far I have found only this library which was last updated about a decade ago:
[Nekodrive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/nekodrive/)

Is there any other way to mount/read/write files to NFS using C# and .net7?

Answer (score 2):

The only library I know that is made in 2021 in net standard 2.1 which means is [compatible with .net core 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1) is NuGet [NFS-Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NFS-Client).

The source code for the solution to be found https://github.com/SonnyX/NFS-Client

As you can see in the code base, it is compatible with version NFS Client v.4 as well as 2 and 3.

[image: NFS Client]

> I have not used this library before but is suggested by a friend of mine.